# Out of memory trying to install ext-gd on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, gd

I have to install ext-gd on my app in Heroku but when I do composer update it fails because of not enough memory. I am using free tier.

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18947584 bytes)

It seems that I can't change memory size, also I don't understand if it's possible to consume all memory just with a composer update.

[Error in Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3zz8.png)

Comment: You have exceeded 1/2 a GIG. Thats sounds a little excessive. And as this is the PHP CLI where there is not usually a memory limit, even odder

Comment: Yes I also think that it's too much memory. I restarted the dynos and result was worse, I had the same memory limit but fails to allocate only  20000 bytes. It's not a complex app, I don't know why it needs so much space.